# Form is not allowed as the type of the inlined record could escape

Tags: compiler-errors, ocaml, record

```
type 'a queue = Q of {estack : 'a list; dstack : 'a list} | Empty

let enqueue d q = match q with  
    | Empty -> Q {estack = [d]; dstack = []}
    | _ -> Q {q with estack = q.estack :: d}
```

Why is the compiler complaining ?

> This form is not allowed as the type of the inlined record could
>   escape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most probably wanted to write some variations of

```
let enqueue d q = match q with  
| Empty -> Q {estack = d; dstack = []}
| Q r -> Q {r with estack = r.estack @ d}
```

The compiler error 
`This form is not allowed as the type of the inlined record could escape` stems from the fact that inlined record are not completely first class object in OCaml. In particular, they cannot be used outside of the context of their constructor. Consequently, when type checking `Q { q with … }` the type-checker tried to unify the type of the variable `q` with the type of the `Q`-inlined record and raised a error because such unification would leak the inlined record of `Q` to the outside variable `q`.

EDIT:

Since your edited version has exactly the same problem, here is
the corrected version

```
let enqueue d q = match q with  
    | Empty -> Q {estack = [d]; dstack = []}
    | Q r -> Q {r with estack = d :: r.estack};;
```

As before, the problem is that in `Q { q with … }` `q` has type `'a enqueue` whereas the constructor `Q` expects as argument a variable of type `'a enqueue.Q.inlined_record`; which does not have an explicit name in OCaml surface language. It is therefore needed to first extract the inner record by pattern matching on `Q r` then update this record with `Q { r with … }`.